# How to assign perl cgi url query string to variable?

Tags: perl, cgi

Please suggest how to assign query_string values to individual variable ?

```
my @values = split(/&/,$ENV{QUERY_STRING});

foreach my $i (@values) {
    ($fieldname, $data) = split(/=/, $i);
    print "$fieldname = $data<br>\n";
}
```

I am getting values below. I am trying to assign to individual values like $org, $value,$source,$target.

```
key =  MAIN
value = test
source = master
target = 123
```

Comment: No issues. I found the solution. I pushed the values and and assigned to variable from array like below.  @urlvalues, $data;
}


my $key = $urlvalues[0];
my $value = $urlvalues[1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, manual parsing of CGI parameters using code like that went out of fashion twenty years ago. You could be far better advised to use the [`param()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Fetching-the-names-of-all-the-parameters-passed-to-your-script) method from CGI.pm.

```
use CGI 'param';

foreach my $fieldname (param()) {
  print "$fieldname = ", param($fieldname), "\n";
}
```

You could declare the variables directly.

```
use CGI 'param';

my $key =   param('something');
my $value = param('something else');
# etc...
```

But perhaps it's better to store your parameters in a hash.

```
use CGI 'param';

my %param;
foreach (param()) {
  $param{$_} = param($_);
}
```

And finally, it's 2015. Why are you still writing CGI programs?

Comment: Thanks for your input